# How to bring n rows into a single line recursively

Tags: unix, awk, sed, text-processing, tr

Can someone please help me to bring n lines of the file into a single line.

Here is the example I am trying to achive:

```
$ cat samplefile.txt
aaa AAA  XX
bbb BBB  AA
ccc CCC AA
ddd DDD 12
eee EEE 3
fff FFF
ggg GGG 3 
hhh HHH4 55
iii III 33
jjj JJJ

$ cat desiredfile
aaa AAA XX bbb BBB AA ccc CCC AA ddd DDD 12 eee  EEE 3
fff FFF ggg GGG 3 hhh HHH4 55 iii III 33 jjj JJJ
```

Here n=5 , I need to have every 5th line as delimiter. Not sure how to achive this. Please advice.

Comment: yes sir, I did tried before asking this here. not good with AWK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This prints spaces between lines except for every fifth line when it prints a newline:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s",$0,(NR%5?OFS:ORS)} END{print""}' samplefile.txt 
aaa AAA  XX bbb BBB  AA ccc CCC AA ddd DDD 12 eee EEE 3
fff FFF ggg GGG 3  hhh HHH4 55 iii III 33 jjj JJJ
```

#### How it works

awk implicitly loops over all lines in a file

- `printf "%s%s",$0,(NR%5?OFS:ORS)`

  This does a formatted print of two strings.  The first string is `$0` which is the line that we just read.  The second string is the result of the ternary statement:

  ```
  `NR%5?OFS:ORS`
  ```

  `NR` is the number of lines read so far.  `NR%5` is the number of lines read so far modulo 5.  If `NR%5` is nonzero, then this statement returns the output field separator, `OFS`.  By default `OFS` is a space.  If it is zero, then the statement returns the output record separator, `ORS`.  By default, `ORS` is a newline.  Thus every fifth line, this ternary statement returns a newline.  On other lines, it returns a space.
- `END{print""}`

  After we reach the end of the file, this prints a newline.  This assures that we have at least one newline at the end of the output.

Comment: THANKS IT WORKED, cAN YOU PLEASE EXPLAIN THE COMMAND ?

Comment: @user5584716 Glad it worked.  I just added an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -vl=5 'ORS=++c%l?" ":"\n"' file
aaa AAA  XX bbb BBB  AA ccc CCC AA ddd DDD 12 eee EEE 3
fff FFF ggg GGG 3  hhh HHH4 55 iii III 33 jjj JJJ
```

Explaination:

++c auto count

++c % l == 0  <=> 5 % 5 == 0           ===> ORS="\n"

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;s/[^\n]*/&/5;Ta;y/\n/ /' file
```

Keep appending lines to the pattern space until pattern matches the required number of matches (in this case 5) then replace each newline by a space.

An alternative using paste is:

```
paste -sd'    \n' file
```

Where the option delimiter (`-d`) contains four spaces and a newline (`\n`).

Or make it programmatic:

```
paste -sd"$(printf '%*s\\n' 4)" file
```

And imagine the first line starts at zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xargs` and tell it to read 5 lines at a time. Its default action is to echo its arguments, which is what you want:

```
xargs -L5 < samplefile.txt

aaa AAA XX bbb BBB AA ccc CCC AA ddd DDD 12 eee EEE 3
fff FFF ggg GGG 3 hhh HHH4 55 iii III 33 jjj JJJ
```